# install error in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

when installing ubuntu in computer, error occurs in computer.
In error, "unknown chip XID 54a" like this.
What is error, and what is solution of this error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozY0f.jpg)

Comment: At what point do you see the error? What are your system specs?

Comment: In grub part occurs error like that

Comment: Please provide screenshots and more info about your system.

Comment: 18.04 uses an older kernel. Please try Ubuntu version 20.04 which is the current long term support release.

Comment: I added picture of error.

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening on a computer with an Asus motherboard, then there’s a high probability that the “Secure Boot” keys are not being properly loaded during installation.

To resolve this, you will need to reset the BIOS on the motherboard and ensure “Secure Boot” is disabled. If it is, toggle it on, then back off again. After doing this, you should be able to install an OS.